# Cannot resume saved Virtualbox state

Tags: virtualbox, cpuid

I get the following error after upgrading via Migration Assistant my laptop from a 2-core to a 4-core processor:

> cpum#1: X86_CPUID_FEATURE_ECX_MOVBE is not supported by the host but
>   has already exposed to the guest [ver=17 pass=final]
>   (VERR_SSM_LOAD_CPUID_MISMATCH).

How can i resolve the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution may be as simple as clicking the big yellow "Discard" button, which will delete the saved state (same as pulling the power cord).

Reference: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=19351

Answer (score 3):

For people working via a terminal.

The accepted answer correctly mentions to discard the current state of the VM. [This basically means pull the power cord, so that the next time you start it, the machine reboots.](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-discardstate)

You can do this using

```
VBoxManage discardstate "your machine's name"
```

Answer (score 3):

Click on the name of the virtual machine, right click on the menu and discard saved status

Answer (score 1):

The Discard button worked for me. Thanks @Justin!

I've been chasing this exact error message off and on for months (fortunately my VM is not part of my daily work). The whole time I thought that it was an issue of being on a new CPU (based on `CPUID_MISMATCH`) so I was looking at how to move a VM from one CPU to another and how to change the expected CPUID. But everything I found in that searching required that you save and shut down properly on the original CPU, which I no longer have.

Simply "Discard"-ing the "Current State (changed)" version worked for me on all of my saved machines.

Whoda thunk that the fix for a virtual Windows machine was a hard reboot? Not like that works for hardware-based Windows boxes, right? ;-) I guess that's why they call rebooting "the Windows Panacea".

Thanks again.